# PGP Encrypting / Decrypting with Apache Camel: Key not found in keyring

Tags: encryption, apache-camel, pgp

I am trying to achieve PGP encryption/decryption with Apache Camel (XML DSL).

I created an OpenPGP key set with Kleoptra (and tested to validate keys work for encryption and decryption)

Now, in my camel context, I have the following:

```
<dataFormats>
    <pgp id="encrypt" keyFileName="party2public.pgp" keyUserid="party2"/>
    <pgp id="decrypt" keyFileName="party2private.pgp"/>
</dataFormats>

<route id="encrypter">
    <from uri="file:ToEncrypt"/>
    <marshal ref="encrypt"/>
    <to uri="file:Encrypted"/>
</route>

<route id="decrypter">
    <from uri="file:ToDecrypt"/>
    <unmarshal ref="decrypt"/>
    <to uri="file:Decrypted"/>
</route>
```

When encrypting a file, it works as expected, file end up encrypted in the Encrypted folder. But when trying to decrypt it, I get the following error:

> org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException: PGP message is encrypted with a key which could not be found in the Secret Keyring.

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to add password="" on your pgp decrypt bean.

I'm fixing that upstream by the way: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12897